# Simple map operations in Groovy (specifically : addition of maps)

Tags: groovy, dictionary, addition

I have a problem properly understanding map operations

```
def map1 = [ name: 'John']
def map2 =  [ name: 'Jane']

assert [ name: 'Jane'] == map1 + map2
```

I would like to get a resulting map like

```
[[ name: 'Jane'], [ name: 'John']]
```

Comment: `[[ name: 'Jane'], [ name: 'John']]` is a list of maps, not a Map in its own right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
map1 + map2
```

it combines the maps, with the right hand map overwriting any keys it has in common with the left hand map..

so:

```
[ a:1, b:2 ] + [ b:3, c:4 ] == [ a:1, b:3, c:4 ]
```

What you want is a list of maps. One option is:

```
[ map1 ] + map2
```

Which wraps map1 in a list, and then adds map2 to this list

```
assert [[ name: 'John'], [ name: 'Jane']] == [ map1 ] + map2
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting "list of maps", tim. Although I understand you explanation, it remains confusing, as this examples show apparently non consistent results : 
`

Comment: `def mapOne = [[ id:1 , firstName : 'Jimmy'], [ id:2 , firstName : 'Robert']]
 def mapTwo =  [ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']
 def mapThree =  [ id:2 , lastName: 'Plant'] 
 def mapFour =  [ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']

 assert mapOne + mapTwo + mapThree + mapFour ==  [[ id:1 , firstName : 'Jimmy'], [ id:2 , firstName : 'Robert'],[ id:1 , lastName: 'Page'],[ id:2 , lastName: 'Plant'],[ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']]
 assert mapThree + mapFour == [ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']
`

Comment: in the first assert, `mapOne` is a List of Maps already, so you just add other maps to the list.  In the second assert, `mapThree` and `mapFour` are maps, so the key overwriting I describe in my answer occurs, and you just end up with `mapFour`

Comment: Also, `[map1, map2]` is equivalent to `[map1]  + map2` and it might be easier to grasp. Depends on how the OP wants to use this I guess.

Comment: and when I try a test loop, I get something wrong : `map = [:]
map2 = [ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']
i = -1
while ( i++ < 2 ){
 map = [ map ] + map2
 ui.informationMessage(ui.frame, " test 1 : " + map.toString() +"\n" )
}

assert map == [[[[:],[ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']],[ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']],[ id:1 , lastName: 'Page']]`

Comment: @epidemian Yeah, but if `mapOne` is a list of maps already (as in the comment above), you will end up with a list containing a list of maps, and a map...

Comment: @MichelParmentier You're wrapping `map` in a list every time you loop...  You're going to end up with a lot of lists of lists of lists of lists of maps...  Start with `map = []` and don't wrap it on the line `map = map + map2`

Comment: @MichelParmentier I believe the last code you posted in the comments can be completely replaced by `def map = (1..3).collect { [ id:1, lastName: 'Page' ] }`

Comment: thanks tim, that was it ! With the semantic in mind (maps vs list of maps) it's much easier to understand your explanation :)

Comment: @tim_yates, Ok, now I understand, thanks. Though, I must say that the line `map = []` is very confusing hehe. Also, if you'd like to add one-key maps like that to the list every now and than, I would recommend doing something more explicit, like `listOfMaps << aMap` or the equivalent `listOfMaps.add aMap`, which does not involve some list-wrapping magic on the second operand :)

Comment: btw sorry for leaving this line : `ui.informationMessage(ui.frame, " test 1 : " + map.toString() ` which should not be included here; it comes from the interaction with Freelane interface

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanations. I did overly simplify my examples to avoid clutter; here it my actual code :  `def myMap =[]
 i = -1
 while (i++ < listOfNodes.size() -1 ){

  def node = listOfNodes[i]
  def text = listOfNodes[i].text
  def company = node['Company']
  def team = node['Team']
  
  myMap = myMap + [name: "$text" , company : "$company" , team : "$team" ]
 }`  I'm not sure I can use you one-liner here tim ?

Comment: @MichelParmentier You can replace that with `def myMap = listOfNodes.collect { [ name:it.text, company:it.Company, team:it.Team ] }`

Comment: @epidemian yeah, sometimes giving variables non-confusing names is half the battle ;-)

Comment: thanks again for your groovy solutions, tim; they reduce the code so much and enlighten my understanding of groovy !

Comment: @MichelParmentier No worries :-)  Glad to help! btw, as @epidemian says, a better name for `myMap` would be `myList` or `myMapList`, to save confusion further down the line ;-)  Good luck!